# What's the meaning of “leave it”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand *leave it* meaning in the bold sentence.
is there any idiom meaning? or if not what *it* refers to?

---

> Mrs. Warren was still trying to remember how long the girl said she meant to stay.
>
> "I think she said as how she didn't know. We **left it** that she'd spend the night, and let me know next day if she nneeded the room any longer."
>
> "What did she do for the rest of the evening?" asked Sir Robert. "She come down to the kitchen and had her supper -- just picked at it

Comment: it refers to the conversation and the implied decision that came from it.

Comment: Do you have a link to the text?

Comment: Mrs Warren had been discussing how long the girl might stay (the conversation)  They left the conversation, i.e., they stopped discussing it, with the understanding that the girl would spend the night ...

Comment: It sounds to me like a shorter version of *[leave it at that](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/leave)* 9th entry under 'phrases': "Abstain from further comment or action"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote marks tell us that this is a conversation. The use of "as how" with the meaning of "that" suggests that this is British regional dialect perhaps from about one hundred years ago. "Left it" here seems to mean "decided". In the case of informal regional conversations all you can do is guess from context which is what I'm doing. I don't claim to be correct.